# How to setup constantinople fork for private ethereum chain

Tags: go-ethereum, constantinople

I am trying to add the constantinople fork to my private net with is running on geth. I have updated to latest geth, geth 1.8.23.

I have stopped my current geth node running and have chnged the genesis file by adding constantinople block as below in config file

> "config": {
>           "chainId": 56312,
>           "homesteadBlock": 0,
>           "eip155Block": 0,
>           "eip158Block": 0,     ***"constantinopleBlock": 16275,***     "byzantiumBlock": 0
>       }

However, when I try to init the geth with new config, O am getting below error

```
Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: mismatching Constantinople fork block in database (have <nil>, want 16275, rewindto 16274)
```

Could someone help me to add constantinople fork to my private net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried this and worked (but I recommend to create a backup):

**=>** `xxxxxx` is the future block number you want to do hardfork your private ethereum chain.

**1-** Alter the .json file by adding `"constantinopleBlock": xxxxxx, "petersburgBlock": xxxxxx`. `PetersburgBlock` is the `Constantinople` fix due to a security hole of `Constantinople`.

**2-** Run the command: `geth --datadir <your datadir> init <genesis>.json`

**3-** Restart running your `geth`, and you should see something like follows:

```
INFO [07-10|13:46:36.647] Initialised chain configuration          
config="{ChainID: 23422 ..... Constantinople: <xxxxxx> Petersburg: <xxxxxx> }"
```

and the chain data remains but the `admin.nodeinfo`, node's `enode` is updated.