# Contract not deploying on private network

Tags: contract-deployment, private-blockchain, truffle-migration

I have a smart contract a little bit like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract sc {

    struct element {
        uint96 firstKey;
        uint96 secondKey;
        bytes32 firstData;
        bytes32 secondData;
    }

    mapping (uint96 => mapping(uint96 => element)) elements;

    function add(uint96 _firstKey, uint96 _secondKey, string memory _firstData, string memory _secondData) public {
        element memory newElement = elements[_firstKey][_secondKey];
        if (newElement.firstKey == 0){
            newElement.firstKey = _firstKey;
            newElement.secondKey = _secondKey;
            newElement.firstData = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_firstData));
            newElement.secondData = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_secondData));

            elements[_firstKey][_secondKey] = newElement;
        }
    }

    function validate(uint96 _firstKey, uint96 _secondKey, string memory _firstData, string memory _secondData) public view returns (bool){
        element memory retElement = elements[_firstKey][_secondKey];
        if (retElement.firstKey != 0){
            if ((retElement.firstData == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_firstData))) && (retElement.secondData == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_secondData)))){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's designed to use huge numbers as keys (because bytes32 is not even close to enough).

I compile and test it on Remix VM and Truffle develop and works perfect.

But when I deploy it on my private network, it fails all the time.
In fact, Truffle won't let me migrate and deploy Migrations.sol for starters.

Here's the error when I try to deploy with Truffle to our private network:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'privETH'
> Network id:      4660
> Block gas limit: 0x55d4a80


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xaba670d9e92b559d92280476a4ba775180ce267d7927e59254020f9a5a978dc2
Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.

    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:92:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.0.30 (core: 5.0.30)
Node v10.16.0
```

With Remix, I get to deploy it, but whenever I try to call the add function I get this error:

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? 
>   The execution failed due to an exception.

The ethereum private network is configured like this (parts ommited):

```
"params": {
        "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
        "maximumExtraDataSize": "0xF4240",
        "minGasLimit": "0x1388"
    },
    "genesis": {
        "seal": {
            "authorityRound": {
                "step": "0x0",
                "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            }
        },
        "difficulty": "0x20000",
        "gasLimit": "0x5B8D80"
    },
```

And the parameters when starting the network are (parts omitted again):

```
 --gas-floor-target 900000000 --tx-gas-limit 500000000 --usd-per-tx 0 --force-sealing
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

This is my 1_initial_migrations.js file:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

This is my 2_contracts.js migration for my smart contract:

```
const sc = artifacts.require("sc");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(sc);
};
```

And this is the default Migrations.sol contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled constantinople (and petersburg) opcodes in your private network?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The private network is version 2.5.5 which, I assume, should already have Constantinople in.

Comment: Which client are you using? Usually in private blockchains you have to explicitly enable opcodes in the genesis file, see this for geth https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67794/how-to-setup-constantinople-fork-for-private-ethereum-chain.

Comment: I'm using Parity version 2.5.5 but it is a private network, do I need to add this anyway?