# Simple functions and constructors not working

Tags: solidity, remix, genesis, solidity-0.5.x

I am working with a private blockchain, and am having a problem where simple functions and constructors simply fail to work. For instance:

```
    constructor(address admin) public{

        owner = msg.sender;
        valid_admins[admin] = true;
        valid_admins[msg.sender] = true; // so the deployer can be admin too.
        max_score = 5;
        min_score = -5;
        lecture_tokens = 5;
    }
```

I deployed this, but calling the relevant functions, `lecture_tokens`, `max_score` and `min_score` are all zero, `owner` is `0x000...000`, and calling `valid_admins` on the owner returns `false`.

[image: lecture_tokens, max_score and min_score are all zero]

[image: owner is 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000]

[image: The <code>valid_admins</code> returns <code>false</code> for the address entered in the constructor call]

It seems like everything is returning with zeroes, false, etc - whatever the initial value is for the type. Even this:

```
    function f1() public pure returns(uint) {
        return(10);
    }
```

- returns zero:

[image: A function that consists only of return(10) returns 0]

Does anyone have any idea of what could cause this? Here is the genesis block I used to initialise my blockchain:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId":123 ,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },

    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",     "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x00",     "gasLimit": "0x8000000",     "difficulty": "0x80",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0xb4a06c62c487b418129b816e41890060d0749787",
    "alloc":{
      "b4a06c62c487b418129b816e41890060d0749787":{
        "balance":"6660010005550000100777"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if the contract was deployed correctly?

Comment: @Ismael Well, it was confirmed as deployed in MetaMask. But given that it doesn't seem to have set any of the variables like the constructor said it was supposed to, I wouldn't exactly say 'correctly'.

Comment: It appears you do not have constantinople/petersburg opcodes enabled in you private network, if you are using solc v0.5 it might be the cause. See this how to enable them https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67794/how-to-setup-constantinople-fork-for-private-ethereum-chain.

Comment: This should not even compile. You are using `msg.sender` in your `constructor`. For that to work you need to mark your `constructor` as `payable`.