# solc@0.5.15 and web3@1.2.6 Error "Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas"

Tags: go-ethereum

I created a simple contract and try to run it on Remix. It worked fine. However, when I deployed and excuted in a private ethereum, I got the error "Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from"

I tried to update the web3 and solc, but it still got the error.

Contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.15;                                         
    contract ExternalData {
    string public ETHUSD='7';

    constructor () payable public {
      ETHUSD = '1';
    }
       function getETHUSD () public pure returns (string memory usd) {
            return '7';
       }
}
```

Compile Code

```
const solc = require('solc');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const externalData = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'ExternalData.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(externalData, 'utf8');

const provableAPI = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'provableAPI_0.5.sol');
const src_provableAPI = fs.readFileSync(provableAPI, 'utf8');

var input = {
  language: 'Solidity',
  sources: {
    'ExternalData.sol': {
      content: source
    }
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      '*': {
        '*': ['*']
      }
    }
  }
};

function findImports(path) {
  if (path === 'provableAPI_0.5.sol')
    return {
      contents:
        src_provableAPI
    };
  else return { error: 'File not found' };
}
var output = JSON.parse(
  solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input), { import: findImports })
);


var output_compiled = {
  interface : output.contracts['ExternalData.sol']['ExternalData'].abi
  , bytecode : output.contracts['ExternalData.sol']['ExternalData'].evm.bytecode.object
};

module.exports = (output_compiled);
```

Deploy Code

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile1');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8541"));

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(accounts[0], '123456');

    let _txHash;
    let _err;

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
    .deploy({ data: '0x' + bytecode})
    .send({ gas: '2000000', from: accounts[0] },  (err, txHash) => {_txHash = txHash; _err = err;});

    var externalData = new web3.eth.Contract(interface, result.options.address);
    var ethusd = await externalData.methods.getETHUSD().call();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(interface));

    console.log('Transaction hashId is ', _txHash);

    console.log('Contract deploy to', result.options.address);
};

deploy();
```

Comment: This error message is misleading, and it typically implies that you are trying to call a function which is not implemented in the contract.

Comment: So my guess is that there is no `ExternalData` contract deployed at `address` when you try to execute `dieselprice.methods.ETHUSD`.

Comment: Try to execute it **inside** your `deploy` function (after deploying the contract). If it works there, then it means that it doesn't work outside this function, because you are not awaiting for this function to complete (i.e., you are doing `deploy()` instead of `await deploy()`).

Comment: Sorry the name may get confused. I created a front-end application and tried to get the contract from the ethereum by using abi and address from the deployment. Then executing the contract by calling the method.

Comment: are you sure you it has been deployed?! where do you sign the transactions or unlock you account

Comment: I added calling method in the deploying block, but I still got the same error.

Comment: I added unlocking account in the deployment code "await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(accounts[0], '123456');"

Comment: @PakornKulsirimongkol Do you have constantinople/petersburg opcodes enabled in your genesis file?

Comment: @Ismael  I am using geth 1.9.10, so is it supposed to be included?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup constantinople fork for private ethereum chain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67794/how-to-setup-constantinople-fork-for-private-ethereum-chain)

Comment: @Ismael Yes thank for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The rather unfortunate `Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas` error message is usually misleading, and it typically implies that you are trying to execute a function which is not implemented in the contract.

You say that your execution code is:

```
dieselprice = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
const price = await dieselprice.methods.ETHUSD().call();
```

But you do not say when you are executing it.

If there is no `ExternalData` contract deployed at `address` when you try to execute this code, then `await dieselprice.methods.ETHUSD().call()` would throw this exact error.

Are you sure that you are executing it after executing your deployment code?

If yes, then are you sure that you are waiting for this code (`async function deploy`) to complete?

Try to place your execution code **inside** function `deploy` (after deploying the contract). If it works there, then it means that it doesn't work **outside** this function because you are not awaiting for this function to complete.

---

A clarification on the statement:

> If there is no `ExternalData` contract deployed at `address` when you try to execute this code, then `await dieselprice.methods.ETHUSD().call()` would throw this exact error.

More generally, "no `ExternalData` contract" should be replaced with "no contract which implements a public or external function named `ETHUSD` which takes no input arguments (either explicitly or by declaring a public variable of the same name)".

Comment: I edit the code to make it less confused by adding calling method after finishing deployment, but I still get the same error. Do you have a way to make sure if my contract get deploy properly?

Comment: @PakornKulsirimongkol: My guess would be that `bytecode` is not what you think it is (i.e., it is not the compiled code of the `ExternalData` contract).

Comment: I looked into the output. there are 2 bytecode that are evm.bytecode.object and evn.deployedbytecode.object. When using the frist one, I can deploy the code but can't call a method. For the second one, it got an error of the gas limit "The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas limit"

Comment: I used the same code, but tried to deploy the contract to the public testnet. It worked fine. is The problem is the private ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

I can make it work by include these in the genesis file.

```
    "byzantiumBlock": 5,
    "constantinopleBlock": 10,
    "constantinopleFixBlock": 20
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error happened when I was running the project on Ropsten network but my web3 RPC Provider had Archive node url pointing to mainnet. Changing the url to point to Ropsten fixed the issue.